# Clang Static Analyzer can't start. Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode, clang

Getting this error:

```
2009-09-03 12:44:02.307 xcodebuild[307:10b] warning: compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.analyzer' is based on missing compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.analyzer'
```

This happens when I execute this script from within xcode:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$( osascript << END
tell application "Xcode"
 tell active project document
  set projectPath to path as string
 end tell 
end tell 
return projectPath
END
)

cd "$result"

/Developer/clang/scan-build -k -V xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator2.2.1
```

It worked all fine, but abruptly stopped working after restarting xcode. Clang is still installed and still at that specified path. Any idea what that message means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SnowLeopard and Xcode 3.2, you can run Clang via the menu command: Build and Analyze.